# Process non-existing pages with .htaccess and php code in seo-friendly .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have below `.htaccess` that force `https` and force `www` in url , but also i want to process non existing pages with my 404 php page.

For example below code works for any existing pages but if page not exists, 404 page will be displayed.

In this case, I want to my custom 404 page code handle it with whole `uri/query strings/parameters` that non-existing page is with.

So if `https://www.example.com/w?id=10` called that if it is not exists, it will redirect to 404 page with all query strings param (in this example: id=10)

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<Files ~ "\.sql$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
<Files ~ "\.zip$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ErrorDocument` is made for this.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` in PHP to get the path.